# where to keep external files in play framework while using scala

Tags: scala, playframework

Where should I keep external files in play framework? I tried adding it to `conf` folder, it didn't work. Then I added it in project folder, it didn't work either. I defined the dependency in `build.scala`, but that didn't work as well. That file is supposed to be used in file input stream.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `conf`, including subdirectories, will be available on classpath. Then you can access it in your application.

For example, if you create a `resources` directory in `conf` and put a file in it:

```
 -- app
 -- bin
 -- conf
   - resources
       - myfile
 ...
```

Then you can get the contents as:

```
val stream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/myfile")
val content = io.Source.fromInputStream(stream).mkString
```

You can inspect what gets copied and is made available on classpath by going to `<play root>/target/scala-xx/classes/`.